# Motivation about "Analysis Situs"

Tags: homological-algebra, math-history, simplicial-complex, motivation

I read Poincaré's paper called [Analysis Situs](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/poincare2009.pdf).  And here's the thing about chain complex.

> **(Page 104 in [this file](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/poincare2009.pdf))**

> That being given, let ${ε}^q_{i,j}$ be a number which is equal to zero if ${a}^{q−1}_j$ is not in the boundary of ${a}^q_i$, $+1$ if ${a}^{q−1}_j$ is part of the boundary of ${a}^q_i$ and in a direct relation to ${a}^q_i$ and finally $−$1 if ${a}^{q−1}_j$ is a part of the boundary of ${a}^q_i$ but in an inverse relation to ${a}^q_i$. We agree to write the congruence
> $$\tag{3} {a}^q_i = \sum {ε}^q_{i,j},{a}^{q−1}_j$$
> to express the boundary of the ${a}^q_i$.
> The set of congruences (3) relative to the different $v_p, v_{p−1},\cdots, v_0$ of $V$
> constitute what may be called the schema of a polyhedron.
> Two questions may be posed:
>
> 1. Given a schema, does there always exist a corresponding polyhedron?
> 2. If two polyhedra have the same schema, are they homeomorphic?
>
> Without dealing with these two questions for the moment, we seek some
> conditions a schema must satisfy in order to correspond to a polyhedron.
> Consider one of the $v_{p−1}$, ${a}^{p−1}_1$
> for example; this manifold should separate
> two and only two of the $v_p$ from each other; so that among the numbers ${ε}^p_{i,1}$ we
> have one which is equal to $+1$ and one which is equal to $−1$, and all the others
> are zero.
> This is not all; consider any of the $v_q$, ${a}^q_i$
> for example, and any of the $v_{q−2}$, $a^{q−2}_k$
> for example.
> There are two possibilities: first, where ${a}^{q−2}_k$
> does not belong to ${a}^q_i$, all the
> products $$\tag{4} {ε}^q_{i,j} {ε}^{q−1}_{j,k}$$
> must be zero, for if $a^{q−1}_j$
> does not belong to ${a}^q_i$
> the first factor is zero; while if ${a}^{q−1}_j$ belongs to ${a}^q_i$ the manifold ${a}^{q−2}_k$ cannot belong to ${a}^{q−1}_j$ (otherwise it would belong to ${a}^q_i$, contrary to hypothesis) and the second factor must be zero.

I think this quote's ${\color{Red}{ε}}^q_{i,j} {\color{Red}{ε}}^{q−1}_{j,k} =0$ corresponds to ${\color{Red}∂{\color{Red}∂}}=0$.  However, my question is, if the above idea is correct, I am curious about the questions and motivations that Poincaré thought of when he first thought of the formula that is the origin of $∂∂=0$. I would appreciate it if you could answer the motivation for $∂∂=0$ in the history of mathematics and Poincaré's questions that led to the emergence of $∂∂=0$.

Comment: You may want to read in parallel to Poincare's original work a more modern and more pedagogical [presentation](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/17-dec.pdf) which contains the corresponding $\partial\partial=\emptyset$ on slide 6.

Comment: Poincare wanted to define topological invariants, generalizing the Betti numbers defined earlier for surfaces. In the modern language, he defined homology groups, cycles modulo boundaries. For this to make sense, you have to have $dd=0$. A caveat is that Poincare defined not homology groups but only Betti numbers (maybe also torsion numbers, I am not sure). I think Stilwell discusses some of this in his translation of Poincare's papers.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hello, thank you for your comment! And I'm sorry for the inconvenience.  In which part of [this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/poincare2009.pdf), translated by John Stillwell, is Poincaré's expression of what is now called $dd=0$?